# SettingWithCopyWarning Python3

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-settingwithcopy-warning

I am finding the max of df2 by row, and setting the max value to new col on df1.

```
df1['max'] = df2[df2.keys().tolist()].max(axis=1)
```

This line is throwing a SettingWithCopyWarning. Not sure how to re-write it to make the warning go away. How to re-write it?

Comment: It looks good to me, you need provide more info.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The warning typically is a result of chained assignments and you can read more about it [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20627316/13330692) and this [blog post](https://www.dataquest.io/blog/settingwithcopywarning/) also goes into great detail.

If you wish to turn it off, you can use:

```
pd.options.mode.chained_assignment = None
```